# HAFA: Missed 14 Day Response Window -- Am i SOL now?

Tags: mortgage, real-estate, foreclosure, short-sale-property, home-loan

I have started the short sale process with Bank of America and I am going through the federal program HAFA.  I initiated the process but delayed submitting documentation longer than the mandated 14 day response window.

I have found documentation around the web that uses language similar to:

> Homeowners must be considered for HAFA within 30 days if they cannot
>   meet HAMP’s requirements or if they specifically request consideration
>   for HAFA. However, the homeowner only has 14 days to respond to a
>   written notice that HAFA may be available to them, giving the lender
>   time to meet their 30-day deadline.

My question is... With HAFA can i reapply? or am I no longer able to do a short sale through HAFA? :(

Comment: Did you ask your banker?  Any answer we can give will be a guess with out knowing your specific circumstance.

Comment: Chad, as far as i know HAFA is government related.  I believe ANY bank would have to adhere to their rules...

Comment: Yes and your banker will know how the rules apply to your case.

Answer (score 1):

Looking online, the HAFA program could be slightly different from lender to lender:

> Requires all servicers participating in HAMP to implement HAFA in
>   *accordance with their own written policy*, consistent with investor
>   guidelines. The policy may include factors such as the severity of the
>   potential loss, local markets, timing of pending foreclosure actions,
>   and borrower motivation and cooperation. - [Source](http://www.realtor.org/government_affairs/short_sales_hafa)

If each implementer is making the program according to their own written policies on timing, cooperation, etc., I don't think there is a generic answer to your question and you'll have to call the lender in question.